# Do I require diff Ad unit ID for each banner ad?

Tags: android, admob

I have 3 banner ads in one activity and 2 interstitial ads for transition between diff apps, do I need diff ad Unit Id for each ad or 2 ad Unit(each for both type) are okay?

Comment: you can use same ad unit id across screens. If you are looking for analytical data, then recommend to use different ad per screen

Comment: I'm planning to put 3 banner in one screen, should I register all 3 banner unit or just one ad Unit ID is fine for all 3 ad?

Comment: one ad Unit ID is fine... refer to this link for banner discouraged implementation policy https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6275345?hl=en